# R getting count of unique values in a table

Tags: r, unique

I have a data as below. I want to get a list of distinct values and their count for the entire matrix.  What is an efficient way to do that?

I thought about putting one column below another (concatenating columns) and creating a single column of 9 elements and then running table command. But I feel that there must be a better way to do this..what are my options?

```
sm <- matrix(c(51,43,22,"a",51,21,".",22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

expected output

```
distinct value: count
51:2
43:1
22:2
a:1
21:1
.:1
9:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `table()` command works just fine across a matrix

```
t<-table(sm)
t
# sm
#  . 21 22 43 51  9  a 
#  1  1  2  1  2  1  1
```

if you want to reshape the results, you can do

```
cat(paste0(names(t), ":", t, collapse="\n"), "\n")

#  .:1
#  21:1
#  22:2
#  43:1
#  51:2
#  9:1
#  a:1
```

Comment: When I tried the table command on the actual data, I got error Error "in table(sm) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"..any idea why?

Comment: What is `length(sm)` or `dim(sm)`? Is it a giant matrix?

Comment: yes. it is a huge data.frame It has 12000 rows and 50 columns

Comment: Still, `12000*50 < 2^31`. Not sure how you're getting that error. Perhaps you could include a sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Is your data a `matrix` like your example or a `data.frame` like you've just suggested it is? Try `table(as.matrix(sm))` or `table(as.vector(sm))`, since `table` on a `data.frame` has a different output which could easily result in the error you've described (this is why examples should represent the real data well). Also, updating to at least 3.0.0 gets you past the 2^31-1 limit.